# how to make show scraping results selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am scraping a page with selenium. I log in and obtain the data, however I would like to have them separated. How do I do that?

I receive them like this...

```
10/11/2022 82542460631 87340554731 38443358142 Sent Email 0.750
```

I would like to save them
in a variable `10/11/2022`,
in another variable `82542460631`,
etc., etc.

This is part of my code. Can you help me?

```
diamondTable = app.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/table')

rows = diamondTable.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr") 

for row in rows:
    print(row.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe i can do it this way:

```
day = rows[0]
number_sequence_one = rows[1]
number_sequence_two = rows[2]
number_sequence_three = rows[3]
```

As I understand it would be

Comment: yes of course, however I don't know how to reflect it in selenium I understand how the logic would be, however when I place the find_elements it generates an error.

Comment: Could you describe the error?